# actionbar dropdown not working when in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation menu bar and a drop-down in the action bar.The UI looks like this:

[image]

For navigation to a different UI I’m using Fragments.When I click on top of the drop-down it should list out all the added items but instead im getting this exception:

```
    06-04 18:12:39.651  22359-22359/com.poliveira.apps.materialtests W/dalvikvm﹕ method Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;
06-04 18:12:39.671  22359-22359/com.poliveira.apps.materialtests D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-04 18:12:39.671  22359-22359/com.poliveira.apps.materialtests W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ce5930)
06-04 18:12:39.671  22359-22359/com.poliveira.apps.materialtests E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:529)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15535)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.measureHeightOfChildrenCompat(ListViewCompat.java:294)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1200)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:584)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.SpinnerCompat.performClick(SpinnerCompat.java:603)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17372)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In MainActivity.java on-create I’m doing this:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

// Enabling Spinner dropdown navigation
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

// Spinner title navigation data
navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Local", R.drawable.deviceonline));
navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("My Places", R.drawable.deviceonline));
navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Checkins", R.drawable.deviceonline));
navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Latitude", R.drawable.deviceonline));

// title drop down adapter
adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navSpinner);
// assigning the spinner navigation
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
```

I’m now having a Fragment class called "ReFragment.java". This the code I'm using:

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView;
        Display d =getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        // set display size
        ThumbSize.setScreenSize(d.getWidth(), d.getHeight());
        final int w = d.getWidth();
        final int h = d.getHeight();
        final double ar = w > h ? (double) w / (double) h : (double) h / (double) w;

        if (ar > 1.6) {
            Log.i(TAG, "AR = " + ar + ", using extended layout.");
            rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.rbox_extended, container, false);

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "AR = " + ar + ", normal layout.");
            rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.rbox, container, false);

        }
       if (mViewFlipper != null) {
            mRemoteView = mViewFlipper.getChildAt(0);
            mMousePadView = mViewFlipper.getChildAt(1);
            mGestureView = mViewFlipper.getChildAt(2);
            mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0); // mRemoteView
        }
        rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mRemoteController = new      RemoteController(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mConfigurationManager = ConfigurationManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        setupButtons(rootView);
        setUpSlider(ar,rootView,mMainactivitiycontext);


       return rootView;
}
```